# Bluetooth device supported to iOS / Android devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

We're having one application requirement in which we required to connect Mobile device to light on/off, blink light on particular light series. We want to search for Bluetooth device which can connect to Mobile and send signal to our devices.

We're aware with Raspberry pie but we're looking for cheap device than Raspberry pie. Anyone can suggest bluetooth device with native SDK which can connect Mobile via Bluetooth and send on / off signal to our devices

Answer (score 0):

You can check BLE modules from vendors like Texas Instruments, Cypress Semiconductors, Silicon Labs, uBlox etc.
Here's an example from Silicon Labs -

https://www.silabs.com/products/wireless/bluetooth/blue-gecko-bluetooth-low-energy-socs

All these offer BLE modules - in either SoC form or just the BLE radio which you can interface with your microcontroller over UART/SPI/I2C.

If you want to interface with iOS device, then look for HomeKit compatible modules which would be having HomeKit certification and the required SDK built in.

HomeKit compatibility will be required if your product is meant to work as a HomeKit accessory using Siri or HomeKit apps. Else you will have to develop and rely on a dedicated app which solely will control the device.

The BLE module vendors also provide development kits on which you can develop your application as a proof of concept before building your final product.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Estimote becaons for my company. I have developed an iBeacon app using Estimote beacons.

The beacons come with an average price.But the support and service from Estimote is very very good. They provide SDK and as well as sample code.

Check the following links. It will give some idea for your requirement.

https://estimote.com/products/

http://blog.estimote.com/post/139902664710/launching-the-most-robust-location-beacons-on-the

http://blog.estimote.com/post/145508085365/extending-the-power-of-your-beacons-with-gpio

https://community.estimote.com/hc/en-us/articles/219001708-How-to-set-up-GPIO-in-Location-Beacons-